# Confuse about javascript function's call method

Tags: javascript, function, call

I read an article about [how speed up javascript](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/), I try copy it's code which could improve loop speed:

```
var chunk = function (array, process, context) {
        setTimeout(function(){  
            var item = array.shift();  
            console.log('item', item);//this could show correctly
            process.call(item, context);  

            if (array.length > 0){  
                setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);  
            }  
        }, 100); 
    }
```

Then I try to pass my parameter into it, but I don't know how to use the `context` parameter, what I have done is:

```
  var dosomething1 = function (item) {
      console.log('this is begin ' + item)
  }

  var dosomething2 = function (item) {
      console.log('this is end ' + item);
  }

  var process = function (item) {
        console.log(item); //this show undefined
        dosomething1(item);
        dosomething2(item);
  }

  var temp = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
  chunk(temp, process);​
```

The problem is begin in the process function, the `item` log `undefined`, the item could only show correctly in `chunk`.

So how can I solve this problem?I think it related to the `process.call` method?Is it related to the context parameter?

You can see the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/NrBmD/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right. .call method is the concept of inheritance in javascript, and the first parameter in .call method is used for passing current object to its super class, and second parameter which is used as normal parameter. Try this,

```
var chunk = function (array, process, context) {
    setTimeout(function(){  
        var item = array.shift();  
        console.log('item', item);//this could show correctly
        process.call(this, item);// the first parameter is the current object
        if (array.length > 0){  
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);  
        }  
    }, 100); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass the context as the first parameter to `call`, `process.call(context, item);`. Though you never pass an argument for context to `chunk` which isn't an issue since you never use `this`.

http://jsfiddle.net/NrBmD/2/

Answer (score 0):

The `call` method of a function calls the function with a specified `this`.  The first parameter you pass the function (in this case `item` in your call to `process.call(item, context)`) will be accessible by the `this` keyword inside your function.

So, make this change to reference properly:

```
var process = function () {
    console.log(this);
    dosomething1(this);
    dosomething2(this);
}
```